# How do you add a resource to a subnet in Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, subnet

I need to protect all my resources (which are in different subnets) by firewall and therefore I need to know how to assign subnet to each resource.

***I am wondering what is the easiest way to connect any resource to a subnet ?***

I have seen different resources which can connect to a subnet by different solution. It is very confusing for me since apparently every resource has its own solution to get connected to the the subnet.

Here are some example:

**Databricks** can be connected by adding `delegation` to subnet as below:

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "private_snet" {
  name                 = "subnet-private"
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.test_vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]

  delegation {
    name = "databricksprivatermdelegation"

    service_delegation {
      name = "Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces"
    }
  }
}
```

However, `azurerm_mssql_server` uses very different resource called `azurerm_mssql_virtual_network_rule`, to place sql database to a subnet as below:

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_virtual_network_rule" "example" {
  name      = "sql-vnet-rule"
  server_id = azurerm_mssql_server.example.id
  subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.example.id
}
```

When it comes to `azurerm_storage_account` it has its own solution called `network_rules` as below:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                = "storageaccountname"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"

  network_rules {
    default_action             = "Deny"
    ip_rules                   = ["100.0.0.1"]
    virtual_network_subnet_ids = [azurerm_subnet.example.id]
  }

}
```

and finally the `azurerm_data_factory` has no argument to connect it to a subnet.

So, in short, my question is:

Is there any easy and straight forward solution which i can setup my resource to a `azurerm_subnet` ?

Comment: Sadly no. As you mentioned it is resource specific.

Comment: Is this something you can do manually on the Azure console??  ... From what you are saying `every resource has its own solution to get connected to the subnet` I get a feeling you should be contacting the Azure tech support team

Comment: > Is this something you can do manually on the Azure console??
console as CLI tooling or portal?

CLI tools have even larger differences between different resource types and it might even more complicate things. Portal should be recommended because OP asked help with templating.

Comment: @Sal-IaS the short answer is no... even in azure portal you would have seen that the networking options are different for different resources and it heavily depends on how the resource is actually implemented under the hood... there is no one stop solution in this case... and as u mentioned in case of data factory there are no argument to connect to subnet as connectivity can only be enabled as private or public end point.. so all the steps are strictly resource specific and cant be generalized

Answer (score 2):

## TLDR

Answer 1: if you want to use service endpoints only there is no simple unified way to configure resources to allow access from subnet. Consider using private links.

Answer 2: Identify different types of Azure service VNet integrations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/vnet-integration-for-azure-services

---

You need to re-iterate your plans and identify what kind of integration your resources have with Virtual Networks.

High-level description of Azure service integration with VNets: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/vnet-integration-for-azure-services

## [Service endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-service-endpoints-overview)

- incoming traffic to resource
- enables resources deployed/injected into subnets to communicate with target resource
- configuration required

  - target resource: allow access from given subnets
  - source subnets:

    - enable service endpoints

      - serviceEndpoints property
    - turn on (VNet Service endpoint policy)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-service-endpoint-policies-overview] for extra safety

      - serviceEndpointPolicies property

Azure changes routing and IP addresses automatically after service endpoint is turned on. No extra interaction is required after adding incoming rule for resource and adding service endpoint support for source subnet.

## [Private endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-link-overview?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-network%2Ftoc.json)

- Private link is similar with service endpoint but newer and can be configured more
- Incoming traffic to resource
- (list of supported services)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/availability]
- Following extra resources are needed

  - private endpoint

    - mostly metadata
  - network interface

    - traffic to this interface is routed to target resource
  - optional private DNS zones and related resources

    - recommended, otherwise usage of IP addresses and/or hosts-file changes are needed
  - optional NSG rules for extra security

## [VNet injection / deployment into VNet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-for-azure-services)

- Azure service is deployed/injected into VNet
- outgoing and incoming traffic goes through VNet
- Some services requires dedicated subnet => only one service type can be deployed into dedicated subnet

---

## Your examples:

### Databricks

Databricks supports [VNet injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/vnet-inject) After deploying databricks into VNet it can securely connect Azure resources that are using:

- service endpoints
- private links
- or are deployed into VNet(same or other subnet, even subnets on other VNet if peering exists)

### Azure SQL

Azure SQL supports both service endpoint and private link. Your example just adds access from services deployed into `azurerm_subnet.example`. "to place sql database to a subnet" does not really happen.

### Storage account

Storage account supports both service endpoint and private link.
`virtual_network_subnet_ids` is just a list that contains allowed subnet ids.

### Data factory

To enable VNet integration with data factory you have two solutions

#### Azure-hosted integration runtime

- enable [managed virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/managed-virtual-network-private-endpoint) feature

#### Run self-hosted integration runtime(SHIR) on Azure VM

- if you run SHIR on Azure then you can use service endpoints and private link to secure connection to other Azure services.

---

## Summary

**First of all: identify your resource types: how they can be integrated with Azure VNets**

Resource firewall/network rules are resource specific like you noticed with Azure SQL and Azure Storage differences. If you need more unified access control and configuration I recommend using private enpoint:

- private endpoint is separated resource type => configuration is independent from target resource
- if extra access control is needed, you can use network security groups to limit traffic into private endpoint

The bicep template [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/create-private-endpoint-bicep?tabs=CLI)(Azure SQL with private endpoint + VM) gives a good high-level overview how private link templating works. Finding correct Terraform resource types should be easier after seeing Microsoft's Bicep examples.

Deployment/Injection to VNet still uses resource-specific configuration/template properties and must be done case-by-case.